# Controlsfx Properties order of items

Tags: javafx, properties, controlsfx

I've a linkedhashmap that I put into Properties file, and it shows the fields in the menu. I've an others color option and I want it to be seen at the end.

So colormap is my linkedhashmap and I put others the end. So when I look inside colormap, last element is Others. But changes when I put it in properties file.

My code is like this:

```
colormap.put("Others",Color.GRAY);
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.putAll(colormap);
```

And order changes inside prop. Do you have any idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `java.util.Properties` type inherits from `java.util.Hashtable` and there is no guarantee that the table will retain its order even after you've loaded the properties.
to fix that you can use [OrderedProperties](https://github.com/etiennestuder/java-ordered-properties)